# Grid row height

Tags: wpf, grid, row

I am trying to increase the height of a row in my grid to the number of items I add in XAML, I'll draw it out to explain and hopefully someone can help me with my problem:

[image]

Comment: Height="Auto" does not work?

Comment: Did u try with stack panel ?

Comment: I'll try using a stack panel, Height="Auto" didn't seem to do anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="43"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="54"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Title"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Scenario 1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Scenario 2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Scenario 3" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Add scenario"/>
</Grid>
```

This will not grow the window, but just the Grid itself.

Comment: Yeah all I need is the Grid row to grow itself thanks :)